# Object was open

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server database with Delphi. The code that I have is placed in a thread and works - meaning I manage to make the restore. The problem is that I get an error from Delphi saying that "Object is open" and the program stops, even though the restore happens successfully. Why am I getting this problem and how can I fix it? Here's the code:

This is the restore thread:

```
type
  TThreadRestoreBackUp = class( TThread )
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    DataSource : TMSDataSource;
    Connection : TMSConnection;
    Query : TMSQuery;
    var
      DBName, RestorePath, dbRPath, dbRLogPath : string;
      differentDB : Boolean;
  end;
```

This is how I call the thread:

```
procedure TfrmCreateBackUp.btnRestoreClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  RestoreBackUp : BackUpThread.TThreadRestoreBackUp;

begin
  RestoreBackUp := BackUpThread.TThreadRestoreBackUp.Create(True);
  RestoreBackUp.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  try
    RestoreBackUp.DataSource := frmMain.MSDSChanges;
    RestoreBackUp.Connection := frmMain.MSConnLyubenAirport;
    RestoreBackUp.Query := frmMain.MSQChanges;
    RestoreBackUp.DBName := edtDBName.Text;
    RestoreBackUp.DifferentDB := tcxCheckBoxNewDB.Checked;
    RestoreBackUp.RestorePath := cxbeChoosePath.Text;
    RestoreBackUp.Start;
  except on EConvertError do
    RestoreBackUp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is the **Execute** function of the thread, aka the code that gets run, when I call the thread:

```
procedure TThreadRestoreBackUp.Execute();
begin
  dbRPath := 'E:\ClientDBS\';
  dbRLogPath := 'E:\ClientDBS\';

  Query.Connection := Connection;
  DataSource.DataSet := Query;

  if DifferentDB then
  begin
    dbRPath := dbRPath + DBName + '.mdf';
    dbRLogPath := dbRLogPath + DBName + '.ldf';

    Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master If DB_ID(' + QuotedStr(DBName) + ') IS NOT NULL BEGIN' +
      ' ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName + '] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE RESTORE DATABASE [' +
      DBName + '] FROM DISK = ' +
      QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
      ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] SET ONLINE END ELSE BEGIN RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName + ']' +
      ' FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath)
      + ' WITH RECOVERY, MOVE ' + QuotedStr('Test') + ' TO ' +
      QuotedStr(dbRPath) + ', MOVE ' + QuotedStr('Test_log') +
       ' TO ' + QuotedStr(dbRLogPath)  +  'END';

    Query.Execute;
  end
  else
  begin
    DBName := Connection.Database;

    Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE' +
      ' RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
      ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] SET ONLINE';

    Query.Execute;
  end;

  DataSource.Free;
  Connection.Free;
  Query.Free;
end;
```

Here's an explanation on how it works: I have a form in which I can choose a path from a tcxButtonEdit, which opens TOpenDialog when the button is pressed. When the path is chosen I have option to press a checkbox, which indicates whether the user wants to restore in the database used, or in a different one. Then the user can enter the name of the different database or the new database if they want to save in another database and not the original. When the button **Restore** is pressed the thread is called and executed. The code inside the thread sets up the things needed for the restore, like paths for the files, connection, tmsQuery and DataSource. Then if it's the checkbox is checked then the if statement receives true, and makes the restore in the different database, if not then it does it in the same.

Comment: If you are doing DB stuff in threads, you must create a new connection for each thread. They can not be shared.

Comment: I am. I've got one for the main form. And I create separate ones in the threads. One for the backup thread and one for the restore one. But I do give them the info needed like DB name and sql server passwords and stuff like that by directly assigning the things from the original connection, dataSource and tmsQuery. But I don't think that's the problem because the backup thread works fine.